# How to use complex / nested bindings with TypedBinding in .NET MAUI C# Markup?

Tags: c#, maui, maui-community-toolkit, maui-markup-community-toolkit

I'm using [TypedBindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/markup/extensions/bindable-object-extensions) in [`CommunityToolkit.Maui.Markup`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Maui.Markup) and my binding is not working as expected when binding to a property nested inside of another property.

In the sample code below, the Label text is updated using the "old" binding method that uses Reflection:

```cs
.Bind(Label.TextProperty, path: "NestedObject.Test")
```

but the Label text does not get updated when using TypedBindings (no reflection):

```cs
.Bind(Label.TextProperty, 
         static (TestModel myModel) => myModel.NestedObject.Test)
```

### Code

```cs
class TestView : ContentPage
{
    TestModel model;

    public TestView()
    {
        model = new TestModel();
        BindingContext = model;

        Content = new Grid
        {
            Children =
            {
                new VerticalStackLayout
                {
                    new Label
                    {

                    }.Bind(Label.TextProperty, path: "NestedObject.Test"),

                    new Label
                    {

                    }.Bind(Label.TextProperty, 
                            static (TestModel myModel) => myModel.NestedObject.Test,

                    new Entry
                    {

                    }.Bind(Entry.TextProperty, 
                            static (TestModel model) => model.NestedObject.Test
                            static (TestModel model, string value) => model.NestedObject.Test = value),

                }
            }
        };
    }
}

partial class TestModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    NestedObject nestedObject = new();
    [ObservableProperty]
    NestedObject? nestedObject2;
    [ObservableProperty]
    string title = "My Title";
}

partial class NestedObject : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    string test = "Initial";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `TypedBindings`, a nested binding requires you to include the `handlers` parameter.

It looks like you're just missing the `handlers` parameter. Below is the updated code as well as a GIF of the working sample app.

I've also submitted a PR here adding the handlers to demonstrate the missing code: https://github.com/Falco94/CommunityToolkit.IssueTest/pull/1

### Updated Sample Code

```cs
public class TestView : ContentPage
{
    TestModel model;

    public TestView()
    {
        model = new TestModel();
        BindingContext = model;

        Content = new Grid
        {
            Children =
            {
                new VerticalStackLayout
                {
                    new Label
                    {

                    }.Bind(Label.TextProperty, path: "NestedObject.Test"),

                    new Label
                    {

                    }.Bind(Label.TextProperty, 
                            getter: static (TestModel myModel) => myModel.NestedObject.Test,
                            handlers: new (Func<TestModel, object?>, string)[]
                            {
                                (vm => vm, nameof(TestModel.NestedObject)),
                                (vm => vm.NestedObject, nameof(TestModel.NestedObject.Test)),
                            }),

                    new Entry
                    {

                    }.Bind(Entry.TextProperty, 
                            getter: static (TestModel model) => model.NestedObject.Test, 
                            handlers: new (Func<TestModel, object?>, string)[]
                            {
                                (vm => vm, nameof(TestModel.NestedObject)),
                                (vm => vm.NestedObject, nameof(TestModel.NestedObject.Test)),
                            },
                            setter: (TestModel model, string value) => model.NestedObject.Test = value),

                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

### Working Sample

[image: Simulator Screen Recording - iPhone 15 - 2023-11-29 at 12 00 37]

### Nested Binding Examples in `CommunityToolkit.Maui.Markup.UnitTests`

https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui.Markup/blob/08459a7e128de0e764f4e293cc191bfa293b79bd/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui.Markup.UnitTests/TypedBindingExtensionsTests.cs#L308-L461

Comment: Good catch! The sample code works fine. Also, you can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem!

Comment: Thanks @AlexandarMay-MSFT, I'm the author of `CommunityToolkit.Maui.Markup`; it'd be quite embarrassing if my answer was not correct .